# dt11 is not detected on raspberry pi 2

Tags: raspbian, gpio, sensor

I am trying to setup dt11 sensor using T-cobbler but its not getting detected.

For reference attaching the screen shots.
[image: wiring]

[image: screen shot]

Any help really appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

By DT11 I assume you mean the DHT11 humidity and temperature sensor.

The principal problem appears to be the very common fault of incorrectly connecting the cobbler.  The ribbon cable appears to be twisted.

To check the cable test the 3V3 and 5V points on the breadboard with a multimeter.  If you read 3V3 where 5V should be and 5V where 3V3 should be the connection is wrong.

A problem of lesser importance is using the Adafruit software which is particularly poor at reading the DHT11 and DHT22 sensors.  However it may have improved since the last time I looked at it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response joan, sure will correct the ribbon and will test with multi meter.